# Calculating acceleration for two or more objects connected by a Pulley rope system

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I understand that there are two commonly used ways to solve problems of this type. One of which is considering the objects separately and using the fact that if the rope doesn't stretch and has no mass then the acceleration of all the objects will be the same.

The second method is one I haven't a clue the logic to it. So, far in my learning of Physics everything has been logical and pretty easy to understand but this is something that I'm stuck on.

The second method is considering the system of objects as one object and then measuring the effect the net external forces has in ratio to the total mass of the system of objects.

First Question: *Why do we only consider the forces external to the system? I have always learned to find the acceleration of a object we consider all the forces that act on that object and divide by the mass of the object.*

Second Question: *When we say we want to find the acceleration of the system, what do we mean by this?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.The 'object' is the system. To find out the motion of the object we only consider forces which act 'on' the object. These are external forces. Any forces inside the object or system are internal forces. Internal forces occur in equal and opposite pairs, acting on different parts of the system, so they have no overall effect on the whole system. The pair for every external force acts on some other object or system : it does not affect our object or system.

2.
The acceleration of the system means the acceleration of the centre of mass (COM) of the system. If the system is a rigid body with a regular shape, the COM will be fairly easy to locate and monitor. If the system is a material which easily deforms and/or has an irregular shape, the COM will be difficult to locate and monitor.